# Setuptools error when installing a local setup.py into virtual environment/Pipfile:

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, pipenv

I can't figure out why I'm unable to run `pipenv install -e .`.

One suspicious thing I notice is, that the error doesn't involve the venv python version (3.8) but the system version (3.11)

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

$ pipenv install -e .

```
full error at bottom of this question
...
ERROR:pip.subprocessor:python setup.py egg_info exited with 1
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 645, in _main
...
```

$ pipenv --venv

```
/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/blu-hkoeInST
```

$ python -V

```
Python 3.8.12
```

$ pip install setuptools

```
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/blu-hkoeInST/lib/python3.8/site-packages (69.2.0)
```

$ pip install -e .

```
Obtaining file:///home/user/src/blu
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

$ cat setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name="blu",
    version="0.1",
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

$ cat Pipfile

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
requests = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
python_full_version = "3.8.12"
```

---

Full error output of `$ pipenv install -e.`

```
Obtaining file:///home/user/src/blu
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
[ra@x blu]$ pipenv install -e .
Installing -e ....
Resolving -e ....
Added blu to Pipfile's [packages] ...
✔ Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock (e91415) out of date, updating to (923111)...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed!
⠙ Locking...False
ERROR:pip.subprocessor:python setup.py egg_info exited with 1
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 645, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 612, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, resolver = resolve(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 592, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       return resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 918, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, hashes, internal_resolver = actually_resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 691, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 448, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv run pip install <requirement_name> to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the versions actually installed in the virtualenv.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: metadata generation failed

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pipenv", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
             ^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/cli/options.py", line 58, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs, windows_expand_args=False)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 92, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 209, in install
    do_install(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 297, in do_install
    raise e
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 281, in do_install
    do_init(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 648, in do_init
    do_lock(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/routines/lock.py", line 65, in do_lock
    venv_resolve_deps(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 859, in venv_resolve_deps
    c = resolve(cmd, st, project=project)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 728, in resolve
    raise RuntimeError("Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!")
RuntimeError: Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!
```

Comment: I guess the project might be missing a `pyproject.toml` file containing a `[build-system]` table listing `seutptools` as build dependency. Could that be?